# Body and Subject fields in Mail Function

Tags: 7, emails

I can't get it working. What am I doing wrong?

```
$name = $form_state['values']['name'];
$rname = $form_state['values']['rname'];
$email = $form_state['values']['email'];
$message = $form_state['values']['message'];

$params = array('current_conditions' => $data);
$message = drupal_mail('wow', rand(0, 999), $email, $language, $params, FALSE);
$message['body'][] = 'test';
// Only add to the spool if sending was not canceled.
if ($message['send']) {
    drupal_set_message('Success!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter you are passing to [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) is `FALSE`. That parameter is telling the function if sending the mail. The documentation describes the parameter as follows:

> `$send`: If TRUE, [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) will call [drupal_mail_system()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail_system/7)->mail() to deliver the message, and store the result in `$message['result']`. Modules implementing [hook_mail_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) may cancel sending by setting `$message['send']` to `FALSE`.

As its default value is TRUE, just leave out that parameter, and the mail will be send, if other modules don't set `$message['send']` to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only prepares message for sending it later. [Example of sending e-mail immediately](http://api.drupal.org/comment/17489#comment-17489):

```
<?php

$my_module = 'foo';
$my_mail_token = 'bar';
$from = variable_get('system_mail', 'organization@example.com');
$message = array(
  'id' => $my_module . '_' . $my_mail_token,
  'to' => 'test@example.com',
  'subject' => 'test',
  'body' => array(
    'line 1',
    'line 2',
  ),
  'headers' => array(
    'From' => $from,
    'Sender' => $from,
    'Return-Path' => $from,
  ),
);
$system = drupal_mail_system($my_module, $my_mail_token);
// The format function must be called before calling the mail function. 
$message = $system->format($message);
if ($system->mail($message)) {
  // Success.
}
else {
  // Failure.
}

?>
```

Edit: changed to better example

Comment: [drupal_mail()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7) calls drupal_mail_system(). There is no reason to call it again after.